# Selenium Node Not Connecting to Hub, Not Opening Port

Tags: ubuntu, selenium

I'm trying to set up a demo selenium grid. I have a Digital Ocean Ubuntu 14.02 droplet. (I actually have two and tried to set this up using two different machines but got nowhere.) I'm trying to run the hub and the node both locally.

Here is my input for both the hub, the node, and nmap results.

https://gist.github.com/mekhami/d5bbecca5ff0de9d2dc9

So, the node is starting up but then the TCP connection is reset and the port it's supposed to operate on is closed.

I have had no luck in any number of different options and configurations to get this to work.

But... of course, it worked randomly once. I don't know why, I don't know what I did, all I know is for one brief moment, the node connected and I saw it on the grid console. Then I tried to run a test and it went down again and I've never seen it come back up.

Please let me know what more information I can provide.

UPDATE: It randomly came online again. I don't know what happened, but it might be related to a timeout or time_wait or something going on.

Comment: why `-role wd` in the node start command? Use `-role node` as in the [documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp#starting-a-node)

Comment: ah, that was part of my experimentation, i generally am using -role node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your VM/server does not have enough entropy available.

To resolve this problem, simply install `haveged` (or other similar things).

The instructions of how to install `haveged` on Ubuntu and other Linux distributions: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-additional-entropy-for-cloud-servers-using-haveged

Answer (score 0):

So, after a great deal of digging, I came upon this. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/14

This thread has a solution to the problem, but I'm re-opening the issue hoping the solution can be rolled into the standalone server.